# How to figure out vagrant ssh port without parsing file or output?

Tags: ssh, vagrant

In order to (integration) tests network applications one might want to setup different vagrant VMs in different directories and configure instances with `vagrant ssh` in the integration test script. `vagrant up` chooses the next available `ssh` port starting from 2222, but that's not predictable enough. I'd like to know if there's a way to retrieve the chosen port after `vagrant up` in order to coordinate commands in the script dynamically.

Parsing the output of `vagrant up` or `Vagrantfile` is the most complicated solution and I'm looking for a better one (something around a oneliner).

Comment: I forgot that I already opened [issue 5696](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5696) of the project. Shortest workarounds are valid answers, of course.

Answer (score 2):

`vagrant ssh-config` will do it, e.g.:

```
vagrant ssh-config | grep Port | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'
```